# Can't display image formatted png on Android

Tags: android

Today I encounter a strange question. I have a png image "image.png", which is generatied by Java code, and anthor image "a.png". I import them to `/sdcard/image/` directory. When I invoke code

```
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image/image.png");
```

and

```
bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image/a.png");
```

on Android, the first bit is null but the latter is not. I am sure the path "/sdcard/image" is right.

Could you help me???

Comment: I think your path is wrong .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of sdcard from this code:

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Then specify the foldername and file name

```
"/image/"+"image.jpg"


bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(extStore +"/image/a.jpg");
```

Comment: Thnx @Nirav Ranpara, for me I think the path is ok, because a.png can show,but the image.png not.